# https certificate ssl has an issue

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf

When I browse to this I get a message saying that there is a problem with the certificate.  Is there anyway to avoid having this happen during my testing without having to tweak ie settings?

I am securing a web service that I will be calling from silverlight.

Will this cause me any issues with silverlight calling?

Edit:
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

and also

The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.

Comment: Edit your question to include the exact message.

Comment: You can create custom ssl certificates with openssl and then use them during development

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the SSL certificate validity for your tests.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

This will globally disable ssl checks. you should add some code around it to make sure it's only skipped for tests.

taken from : http://garfoot.com/blog/2009/01/calling-wcf-services-with-an-invalid-ssl-certificate/

Answer (score 1):

I had to install a certificate on the client machine as well to create trust.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://geekswithblogs.net/scottthompson/archive/2009/03/25/setting-up-ssl-between-silverlight-and-wcf-under-iis7.aspx

Also there where some hotfixes that came out with SP1, that you should look into, if you did not already.